# Editable path in "Save as" option

Tags: nautilus, window, cloud, location, keepass

This happens while saving or opening database of `keepassXC`.

Can't Edit the save path!
Please don't suggest pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

It does not work while saving or opening file. It only works in plain Nautilus.

Also please don't suggest select drive from `/media/`.

As I am trying to save it in google drive.

I already have path for it.

I just need to copy paste it here somehow!

[image: keepass saving window]

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem when trying to save my files from any application in kbuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

here is my way:

Simply paste your absolute path in the "Name" field, before "test.kdbx"

as below :

`/home/user/Desktop/test.kdbx`

Answer (score 0):

I just checked and KeepassXC does not seem to have a field for that. You would have to navigate the filesystem and select the database file to open.

That is certainly strange, as I supposed it should not depend on the application but on the desktop manager...
but that's how it is.

Comment: can't navigate to there. Its in root directory. It says permission denied. As now we are able to mount gdrive by logging in ubuntu account setting. we can access path directly without needing root access with command "nautilus google-drive://email-id/" and "google-drive://email-id/" this is the path I am trying to put in

Comment: Or is there any way to run keepass as sudo? so that it won't say permission denied?

Comment: I suggest you edit the question with more details, help others help you.
Please 1) Post your command to mount the gdrive, 2) Post an image of nautilus, showing the gdrive, 3) Post the exact commands and message in connection to "permission denied" (or sequence if not at the command line).
PS: If you can mount the gdrive, I guess it is already part of your filesystem. You should be able to navigate there, unless the way you mounted it does not allow for that. Perhaps you could set a soft link from your home directory straight to the mount point.
I will wait until you post the details.